# Having issues with adding user input in to a list in python

Tags: python, list, input, append

Ive been working on a password keeper for educational purposes and would like the user to be able to create an account if they dont already have one. I figured the best way to do this was to have a separate list for usernames and one for passwords. If the user is creating an account, just append the username and password to their respective lists, it isn't appending anything. Maybe I have my syntax wrong? I looked up several websites to check my syntax and everything looked ok. What am I missing?

Here's the relevant chunk of code:

```
def main():
    users=['ari']
    passwords=['rycbar1234']
    # This is the "title screen"
    print('_____This is a password keeper_____')
    # checking if the user has an account
    actCheck = input('Do you already have an account?')
    if actCheck == 'Yes' or actCheck == 'yes':
        # asking for user's name and password
        yourUser = input('___What is your Username?___')
        yourPass = input('___What is your Password?___')
        if (yourUser in users and yourPass in passwords):
            dirCheck = input('Account settings?[y,n]')
            if dirCheck == 'y' or dirCheck == 'Y':
                # This is the start of the password/username thing
                print('this function is not working yet!')
                actSetCheck = input('Change username or password?')
                if (
                                        actSetCheck == 'user' or actSetCheck == 'User' or actSetCheck == 'Username' or actSetCheck == 'username'):
                    yourNewUser = input('What would you like your new username to be?')
                elif (
                                        actSetCheck == 'pass' or actSetCheck == 'Pass' or actSetCheck == 'password' or actSetCheck == 'Password'):
                    yourNewPass = input('What would you like your new password to be?')
            elif dirCheck == 'n' or dirCheck == 'N':
                request()
        # incorrect password thing
        else:
            print('Incorrect Username or password')
    else:
        print('This function is not working yet!')
        createAct = input('Would you like to create one?')
        if createAct == 'yes' or createAct == 'Yes':
            createUser = input('What would you like your username to be?')
            createPass = input('What would you like your password to be?')
            users.append(createUser)
            passwords.append(createPass)

        else:
            main()


main()
```

Comment: i think your missing some characters ...

Comment: could you please elaborate?

Comment: you have an incomplete line towards the end. Your line is just `passwords.`

Comment: @JoranBeasley It's been fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 36 has a syntax error. `passwords.` is certainly not valid syntax. You probably meant to write `password.append(createPass)` which would also explain why everything wasn't being appended.

Additionally, I'm sure you're aware but this is an extremely unsafe thing to do outside the context of class or academia. When storing passwords, you should always salt and appropriately hash before storing.

Last note, it may be cleaner to store username and password in a tuple and then place those into a list. This will bind the user and the password to a single object allowing you to do things like sort the list. This is preferred to parallel arrays/lists, as you have now, because of this fact (its also a lot more pythonic).

By way of example:

```
users = []
for i in range(num_new_users):
     user = input("username:")
     pass = input("pass:")
     users.append((user,pass))
users.sort()
```

**EDIT:**

To explain in further detail, a tuple is a built-in type in Python. It is formed by wrapping some items in parenthesis. Tuples are very useful for associating a few objects with one another. We prefer them to lists in many cases as they are immutable. This mean that you cannot change their value or size once they've been created, but they can still be accessed using the familiar list notation. A simple example of creating a tuple follows:

```
>>> x = (1,2)
>>> print x
(1,2)
>>> print x[0]
1
>>> x[1] = "hello"
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

The reason this is useful in your example is because it take you from two lists, where you assume that any index corresponds to the same user, down to one list where you know they do. Consider this example:

```
>>> usernames = []
>>> passwords = []
>>> for i in range(5):
...     usernames.append(input("Username:"))
...     passwords.append(input("Pass:"))
```

Here, `usernames[0]` and `password[0]` are associated with the same user. But what happens when we change something about one of the lists without the other? If we continue with the previous code and execute the following command:

```
>>> passwords.sort()
```

All of the sudden there is no guarantee that `usernames[0]` and `password[0]` are associated with the same user. Now using tuples instead of parallel lists:

```
>>> users = []
>>> for i in range(5):
...     username = input("Username:")
...     password = input("Pass:")
...     users.append((username,password))
```

We have explicitly linked the username and password because they are stored in the same object. Now when we execute:

```
>>> users.sort()
```

We can guarantee that the information returned by `user[0]` will always be associated with one another. Try out both of these example in your python interpreter. Use lots of print statements so you can see what is going on. Hopefully you'll see this is a much better way of doing things.

Comment: To add on to what you said, if you don't use a tuple and you somehow are missing one username or one password then the entire list is wrong. OP should definitely switch from the two arrays to a single array of tuples

Comment: Yep! I didn't catch the passwords syntax thing. The username wasn't appending either though. I had a very hard time understanding what you said in the last bit and your example even after doing some research. Could you please try to explain it in a different or more specific way? Thanks!

Comment: So just to be clear, Make a list of tuples. So once the account has been created, it will be created in a tuple, and the tuple will be placed in a list. Also, when I have either "createUser" or "createPass" in the append statement, my IDE seems to expect another thing and I'm not sure what would go there.

Comment: @AriMadian please see my edits, per your request. Also please accept an answer once you've found a solution that works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the edits! It helped me understand what you were trying to say. One thing though, I see you and other people in this thread using a string similar to "for i in range(5):". What is the purpose of this?

Comment: @AriMadian Glad to hear it. Not trying to be pushy but could you please 'accept' my answer so I can get the appropriate rep for it? I put a lot of work into this answer. The purpose of `for i in range(5)` is to cause the loop to iterate 5 times. In python, you must supply an "iterable" to a loop, which is easy to understand when dealing with lists. This is no different as the `range(n)` method returns a list from `0 to n - 1`. I.e. `range(5)` will return `[0,1,2,3,4]`

Comment: Okie dokie! Ill try out the edits but ill keep the post unanswered for now so I can get some more feedback. Once I feel like I have enough, Ill click the check!

Comment: I tried out the edits you suggested and it works, just not if I want to run it again and use the new login. It appends the input, but only for that "session" so if I start the program again, the tuple is no longer in the list. I appreciate all of your help!

Comment: You'll need to write out the contents of the users list to a file and read it back in on the 'session'. Use google and stackoverflow to research how to do that yourself (its very easy). As a note, users on stackoverflow are not your personal debuggers. **You should ask one question and when you get an answer, accept it**. If you have _small_ follow-up questions that are directly related to the original question you asked, you can post in the comments. Otherwise you need to ask a new question...not hold rep hostage until you're done.

Comment: Please don't be snarky. I came here to ask a question because I had done research, and couldn't fix my problem. I have had small follow up questions, and I don't see whats wrong with asking them? I am not using stack overflow as my "personal debuggers" and have been very careful not to in the past. I only come here when I am stuck, and have done research and not found any answers. I appreciate the help, but I wasn't "holding rep hostage". Why should I mark the question as answered if it hasn't been answered?

Comment: My apologies @AriMadian, that was not my intent. We just don't want questions that start with one thing and end with another, or that are considered "chatty." Your original question was about a syntax error. That question was answered on the first line of my response. The additional suggestions were designed to help you have a better outcome with your project, so it seems rash to "un-accept" my answer. Sorry if I offended you, just trying to keep discussion on topic.

Answer (score 0):

First, in the 'not working' area, you have:

```
passwords.
```

Which is a syntax error. I suspect this is just a typo, though.

I think your real problem is that you are attempting to store 'users' and 'passwords' as local variables in main(), update them, and then call main() recursively.

Since 'users' and 'passwords' are local variables, they will be updated in the previous call to main. However, the variables in the new call are completely separate.

To address this, either make them global variables, or pass them into main. For the global approach:

```
users = ['user']
passwords = ['default']

def main():
  # use the 'users' and 'passwords' as usual
```

For the pass-in approach:

```
def main(users, passwords):
  # use 'users' and 'passwords' as usual

main(['user'], ['password'])
```

Of course, don't try to implement a password system for real unless you know what you're doing :)

Comment: So just to be clear, to do the global approach, Just move the lists outside of the function? That's it? I tried it and it didn't work so I tried using the 'global' statement on both createUser and createPass and it still didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: You shouldn't need the global keyword -- just declaring at file scope should do the trick. Global keyword is used to create or reassign a global variable from within a function. The other issue is the nesting of your recursive call to main(). It will only get called if the user answers 'no' to creating an account, otherwise main() will return. I suggest getting rid of the else and moving the recursive call to main() into the overall def main(): block.

Comment: Still not working with the global thing... Any ideas? I fixed the main() thing though.

Comment: Hmm, I tried making those changes to your code, and it did work. I'd recommend adding in print statements for users and passwords (at the beginning of main, for example) and debug from there.

Comment: Thanks, I tried using the print statements and another edit, and the append command works, but only for the duration of that "session".

Comment: If you'd like passwords to persist after you close the program, you must save and load them to a file: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html